# Dynamically adding buttons to toolbar in Telerik MVC grid

Tags: razor, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

Is there a way to programmatically add a number of items to the [Telerik MVC Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid)'s tool bar?

I would normally manually add items like this but have a collection of items I'd like to add to the toolbar and wondered if there was a way to achieve this?

```
.ToolBar(commands =>
{
   commands.Custom().HtmlAttributes(new { id = "btn-addproduct" }).Text("Add Product").HtmlAttributes(new { onclick = "addQuotationLine(" + Model.Id + ");return false;" });
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter for the configurator is an action, so you should be able to put any valid c# in there. This worked for me:

```
.ToolBar(commands =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        commands.Custom().Text("hello" + i);
    }
})
```

Just change the loop to loop through your collection of items and configure each command accordingly.